# GAC Assembly redirection for several .dlls

Tags: gac, policy, gacutil, global-assembly-cache, publisher-policy

I'm trying to redirect a specific `.dll`, let's call it `MyAssembly.dll`. This assembly has two versions:

```
MyAssembly.dll version 1.0.0.0
```

and

```
MyAssembly.dll version 1.1.0.0
```

I want these two assemblies to redirect to its third version: `1.2.0.0`. 
For that purpose, I wrote this `.config` file to build the `Publisher Policy` to be applied on GAC:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly" publicKeyToken="myPublicKeyToken" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.2.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

With this, I create the appropiate `.config` file to generate the policy. But my problem comes when I want to create the `Policy`.

Note before next step: an assembly versioning works like this:

```
<major version>.<minor version>.<build number>.<revision>
```

First time I wanted to create a Policy, I realized that, if the assembly version I want to redirect is: `1.0.0.0` I had to create a policy that matched like this:

```
Policy.<majorversion>.<minorversion>.<AssemblyName>.dll
```

With this, I'm able to redirect any `MyAssembly.dll` from 1.0.* to up, to version 1.1.

But, how can I generate that policy if I want to redirect more than one assembly, like I explained above? How should my policy look like?

If I have two assemblies:

```
1.0.0.0 - 1.1.0.0
```

How do I build the `PublisherPolicy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx#BKMK_Assemblyunificationanddefaultbinding) article, I had to create *one Policy* for each combination of *MajorVersion.MinorVersion* of my assembly. So I had to create two policies:

- One to be able to redirect from ***1.0.0.0*** to ***1.2.0.0***
- And another one to redirect from ***1.1.0.0*** to ***1.2.0.0***

This solution works, but if anyone knows a more efficient way to do this, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: It's that way by design; you won't find a more efficient way.